# image calling using Json format

Tags: android

I can retrieve normal list from the server but when i am trying to set up the image, its producing "Force to close" . The json file can be viewwd [here](http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/proj/androidjson.php?identifier=123) .A bundle of Thanks in advance. Here is the code.

```
public class Test extends ListActivity  {
      Prefs myprefs = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
        this.myprefs = new Prefs(getApplicationContext());
        // install handler for processing gui update messages
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>(); 
       JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/proj/androidjson.php?identifier=" + 
        Test.this.myprefs.getPersonalno());

        try{

            JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("services");

            for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                 JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id", e.getString("taskid"));
                map.put("pic", "Service name : " + e.getString("employeepic"));
                map.put("serviceinfo", "" +  e.getString("employeename")+ " : "+ e.getString("starttime")
                        +" To " +  e.getString("endtime"));
                  ImageView imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
                 String imageBaseDirectory = "http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/proj/admin/pictures";
                 String imageName = e.getString("employeepic");
                 imgView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageBaseDirectory+imageName));
                    map.put("img",imageName);
                mylist.add(map);            
            }       
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.test,new String[] {"img", "servicename", "serviceinfo" }, 
                        new int[] {  R.id.image ,R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(Test.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });

    }
```

Here is the xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#55000000"
    android:background="#55000000"
    >
      <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="50dip"
      android:layout_height="50dip"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
<TextView  

    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/item_subtitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="18dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the logcat

```
07-06 01:09:18.409: WARN/dalvikvm(101): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
07-06 01:09:18.409: INFO/ActivityManager(101): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.droidnova.android.howto.optionmenu/.Test }
07-06 01:09:18.449: WARN/dalvikvm(101): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
07-06 01:09:19.009: DEBUG/dalvikvm(16327): GC freed 2412 objects / 190240 bytes in 105ms
07-06 01:09:20.829: DEBUG/ImagesWidgetProvider(16291): OnReceive:Action: android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE
07-06 01:09:20.829: DEBUG/ImagesWidgetProvider(16291): onUpdate(): 
07-06 01:09:21.329: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(16327): Shutting down VM
07-06 01:09:21.329: WARN/dalvikvm(16327): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e390)
07-06 01:09:21.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.droidnova.android.howto.optionmenu/com.droidnova.android.howto.optionmenu.Test}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:126)
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932)
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327):     at com.droidnova.android.howto.optionmenu.Test.onCreate(Test.java:56)
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-06 01:09:21.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
```

Comment: It says there's a null pointer at line 56. Which line is 56?

Comment: Its this imgView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageBaseDirectory+imageName));

Comment: this is strange as I'm not assuming that imgView is null. it has to be imageName as this is strange too. Check your JSON if you have 'employeepic' as String

Comment: @ Rafael T yeah it have , you can see at http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/proj/androidjson.php?identifier=123

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

- e has no element keyed 'employeepic'
- there is no R.id.image

It's hard to tell, the way the code is laid out.

Comment: here is the url in which employeepic value can  http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/proj/androidjson.php?identifier=123